# Is there any  signal-processing algorithm that could reverse-engineer how the sound wave was produced through the vocal system of group of humans?

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, audio, signal-processing

Having long sound tape with 3 speakers on it , how to get info on how there mouthes open/close? We have audio recording, with more than one speaker. Sound is clear and does not require noise reduction. We want to create some animation with speaking 3d heads. Generally we want to find out from sound data mouthes movement.

Really we have 3d heads moving somehow via some default animation. Like we have prepared animation for O sound for each person, we need some info: on which millisecond which person produced which sound?

So it is like voice to text but for sounds and for more than one person on one recording.

[image: image with head on it]

In general (perfect case) we want to obtain some signals on movements of D9, D6, D5 point pairs. From more than one speaker, English language of course.

Are there any papers with algorithms or opensource libraries?

So far I have found some libraries

http://freespeech.sourceforge.net/
http://cmusphinx.sourceforge.net/

but I had never used any of them yet...

Comment: Please explain better. What have you done so far? What are the 3 speakers?

Comment: So you want to reverse-engineer how the sound was produced through the vocal system of a human? Interesting, but not really about programming. (Having trouble implementing the algorithm would be programming, but asking for the physics/algorithm is not.)

Comment: to reverse-engineer how the sound was produced through the vocal system of a human one requires signal-processing algorithm such that would show how to do it fram wave to data=)

Comment: Can you please come back and post a reply to this question about what you finally use. I am really fascinated by the problem and would love to know more about it :)

Comment: this is a cool problem.  it is hard and not entirely intractable.  however, i don't think that anyone here will be able to answer it (or, more importantly, want to answer it).  a number of companies are working on this.  if there is an algorithm that works well, it would be important ip...

Answer (score 4):

Interesting problem!! The first thing that came to my mind was to use motion detection to identify any movements at regions D5, D6 and D9. Extend D5, D6, D9 to be rectangles and use one of the approaches mentioned [here](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/audio-video/Motion_Detection.aspx) to detect motion within those reigons.

Of course you have to first identify a person's face and the regions D5, D6, D9 in a frame before you can start monitoring any motion.

You can use a speech recognition library and detect phonemes in the audio stream along with the motion and try to map motion features(like region, intensity and frequency etc.) to Phonemes and build a probabilistic model that maps mouth motions to phonemes.

Really interesting problem!! I wish I was currently working something this interesting :).

Hope I mentioned something useful in here.

Answer (score 4):

This is an instance of the "cocktail party problem" or its generalization, "[blind signal separation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signal_separation)".

Unfortunately, while good algorithms exist if you have N microphones recording N speakers, performance of blind algorithms with fewer microphones than sources is quite bad.  So those are not much help.

There is no particularly robust method I know of (certainly was not as of five years ago) to separate speakers even with extra data.  You *may* be able to train a classifier on human-annotated spectrograms of the speech so that it can pick out who is who, and then possibly use speaker-independent voice recognition to try to figure out what is said, and then use 3D speaking models used for high-end video games or movie special effects.  But it won't work well.

You would be better off hiring three actors to listen to the tape and then each recite the part of one of the speakers while you video them.  You will get much more realistic appearance with much less time, effort, and money.  If you want to have a variety of 3D characters, put markers on the actors' faces and capture their position, then use those as control points on your 3D models.

Comment: I think you a word in your second paragraph.

Comment: actually this isn't quite bss.  he wants to be able to model face movement, too.  it's a much harder problem, albeit tractable.  we do it (er.. our auditory system does it.  we can listen to a speaker and mimic the facial movement).  however, it is an extremely hard problem and several very large companies are working on this.  the first one to come out with something that works well... will make some $.  this is important IP.

Comment: @thang - If the bss problem is too hard, the facial recognition is irrelevant, and with actors you can have better-controlled viewing conditions so you at least get a start.

Comment: @RexKerr actually that isn't strictly true.  this isn't strictly bss because bss assumes you know not thing about the individual sources.  some assumptions are statistical (independence - ica, uncorrelated - pca).  for example, you may want to separate birds chirping from ocean wave sounds.  in this problem, you know that the components are speech signals.  you can use that to your advantage.  so even if bss were not solvable, this problem may be solvable.  facial recognition is totally unrelated here.  i think the OP calls for facial simulation.

Comment: @thang - Well, sure, that's entirely true--you know that _all the signals you care about are speech signals_ which means that you can use high-order information about the temporal structure of speech to help unmix the different speech streams.  You _don't_ have any really simple information like frequency that is likely to do a great deal.  AFAIK this is a research-level signal analysis problem (unless the OP means that the speakers don't talk over each other!).  But this doesn't really add anything to my answer.  Bss is easy to get and probably won't work; the rest is hard.

Comment: @RexKerr I think you are exactly right.  There are some pretty reasonable solutions in the industry, I think.  I've seen some cool demos from a number of companies with varying degrees of success.  Their specific algorithms are most likely patented.  Several dissertations and books have also been written just on this topic.  We also can do it via our brain (probably through years of training), so at least we know that there is one workable solution.

Answer (score 3):

I think that you are looking for what is known as "Blind Signal Separation". An academic paper surveying this is:

> ## [Blind signal separation: statistical principles](http://perso.telecom-paristech.fr/%7Ecardoso/Papers.PDF/ProcIEEE.pdf) <sub><sup><sup>(pdf)</sup></sup></sub>
>
> *Jean-François Cardoso, C.N.R.S. and E.N.S.T.*
>
> Abstract— Blind signal separation (BSS) and independent component analysis (ICA) are emerging techniques of array processing and data analysis, aiming at recovering unobserved signals or ‘sources’ from observed mixtures (typically, the output of an array of sensors), exploiting only the assumption of mutual independence between the signals. The weakness of the assumptions makes it a powerful approach but requires to venture beyond familiar second order statistics. The objective of this paper is to review some of the approaches that have been recently developed to address this exciting problem, to show how they stem from basic principles and how they relate to each other.

I have no idea how practical what you are trying to do is, or how much work it might take, if practical.

Answer (score 1):

Some work that came out of University of Edinburgh about 15 years ago (probably the basis of the voice recognition we have) is applicable.  They were able to automatically turn any intelligible English speech (without the program being trained) into a set of about 40 symbols, one for each distinct sound we use.  That capability combined with waveform signature analysis to identify the human of interest is "all" you need.

This is an engineering problem for sure.  But not a programming problem suitable for Stack Overflow.  I look forward to the day it is though.   :-)